# Fullscreen doesnt work

Tags: java, jframe, render, fullscreen

The screen flashs black up and then the JFrame is opened alone.

```
public Game() {
    myDevice = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    // frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(this);

    myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
    try {
    } finally {
        myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }

    time = 0;
    level = new LevelOne(this);
    this.requestFocus();
    try {
        bgImg = ImageIO.read(new File("Space.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (this.getBufferStrategy() == null)
        this.createBufferStrategy(2);
    bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
        calc();
        MobMover.calc();
        render();
        time++;
        }

    }, 0L, 40L);
}
```

I don't see the problem... :'(

Comment: You have a `try`-block with a sole `finally` clause that sets fullscreen to null. Remember that a `finally` block will always execute. What is even the purpose of that block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code will set it to `null`:

```
try {
    } finally {
        myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }
```

So remove that and it should work.

Comment: Thanks that was stupid xD
But now i have a black bar, where the task bar is usually

Comment: Try add either or both of the following: frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) / frame.setUndecorated(true)